# Was soll / sollte ich machen?

Tags: subjunctive, modal-verb

I understand that the form "sollten" sounds kinder/softer than "sollen" in a formal scenario. For example:

> Sie sollten dieses Buch lesen.

However, **does it make sense in questions, especially when I am refering to myself?**

My question was triggered in a formal e-mail where I was asking about **what I should do** (advice). What would be better? Can they just be interchanged?

> Was sollte ich machen?

or

> Was soll ich machen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two variants can be interchanged, but come with nuances. In general *ich soll* has a more imperative connotation ("What am I supposed to do?", "What is my moral obligation to do?")  and *ich sollte* is asking for an advice ("What is prudent to do?") But these nuances are weak. If you ask *Was soll ich tun* this will be understood as asking for advice, too.

Also be aware that *ich sollte* is not only 1. Pers. Sgl. Konjunktiv Präsens but can also be understood as 1. Pers. Sgl. Indikativ Präteritum.

Comment: Thank you! Do you use "tun" here because it sounds better or because "machen" is wrong?

Comment: Oh, that was just fugacity of reading. Both "tun" and "machen" are as well correct as appropriate.